# Is it posible to have AUTOINCREMENT without setting it as PRIMARY KEY In ANDROID SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

I have tried with INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT while creating Table in Android Sqlite. But it shows error.
But it works fine while giving INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT.

My requirement is that, the column with AUTOINCREMENT shouldn't be a primary key.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Table_KOT_ITEMS_TEMP + "(" + col_Item_Name
                + " varchar(40) NOT NULL," + col_Ref_No
                + " int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'," + col_Table_No
                + " varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'," + col_Kot_No
                + " int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'," + col_Main_Item_Code
                + " varchar(10) NOT NULL," + col_Item_Type
                + " varchar(10) NOT NULL," + col_Item_Amount
                + " decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00'," + col_Item_Qty
                + " decimal(9,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000'," + col_No_Of_Persons
                + " varchar(6) NOT NULL," + col_Dum_Unique
                + " varchar(25) NOT NULL," + col_CheckBox
                + " char(5) NOT NULL," + col_Item_Auto_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)");
```

Comment: Yes, you can make column with AUTOINCREMENT and Column is not necessary to be a primary key.

Comment: nope couldn't. it shows error

Comment: It shows *what* error?

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error: , while compiling: CREATE TABLE KOT_Items_Temp002(Item_Name varchar(40) NOT NULL,Ref_No int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',Table_No varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',Kot_No int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',Main_Item_Code varchar(10) NOT NULL,Item_Item_Type varchar(10) NOT NULL,Item_Amount decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',Item_Qty decimal(9,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',No_Of_Persons varchar(6) NOT NULL,col_Dum_Unique varchar(25) NOT NULL,Check_Box char(5) NOT NULL,Item_Auto_ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT)

Comment: Please put your error message directly in the body of your question, it makes it easier for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, It's pretty difficult to achieve that, the only option is to give it as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT...

Comment: @user2746120 As I already wrote in my answer, it is possible, but not very beatuiful. This answer just tells you the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. But you can create a trigger that does that.

```sql
 -- Create table
 CREATE TABLE testtbl (
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     autoincr DEFAULT NULL,
     otherrow TEXT -- and maybe more
 );
 -- Create helper table
 CREATE TABLE sequence_helper (
     name TEXT PRIMARY KEY COLLATE NOCASE,
     seq INTEGER DEFAULT 1
 );
 -- Fill in the starting number
 INSERT INTO sequence_helper VALUES ('testtbl', 1);
 -- Create the trigger
 CREATE TRIGGER autoincr_testtbl AFTER INSERT ON testtbl FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     UPDATE testtbl SET 
         autoincr = (SELECT seq FROM sequence_helper WHERE name = 'testtbl')
         WHERE rowid = new.rowid;
     UPDATE sequence_helper SET seq = seq+1 WHERE name = 'testtbl';
 END;
```

You can probably improve this by checking if the autoincr column is `NULL`, but you should get the basic idea.

Comment: Probably I should adopt the naming conventions from the  [sqlite_sequence](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab) table.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, an `AUTOINCREMENT` column [must be declared as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).